# mutual independence of X, Y, T, Z implies independence of (X+Y, X+T) and Z?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables, independence, characteristic-functions

I came up with a proof by the method of characteristic function, but it might be too simple to be true. So I am unsure about that.

The problem is as follows: suppose four random variables X, Y, T and Z are mutually independent, then the random vector (X+Y, X+T) and the r.v. Z are independent?

Here is my argument:

For any $(t_1,t_2,s) \in \mathbb{R}^3$,

\begin{align}
\phi_{X+Y,X+T,Z}(t_1,t_2,s)&= \mathbb{E}[e^{it_1(X+Y)+it_2(X+T)+is Z }] \\
&=\mathbb{E}[e^{i(t_1+t_2)X+it_1 Y+it_2 T + is Z}] \\
&=\mathbb{E}[e^{i(t_1+t_2)X+it_1 Y+it_2 T}]\mathbb{E}[e^{is Z}] \qquad\text{(by the mutual independence)}\\ 
&=\phi_{X+Y,X+T}(t_1,t_2)\cdot\phi_Z(s)
\end{align}

So $(X+Y, X+T)$ and $Z$ are independent.

Did I miss some points here?

Comment: Your proof is correct. More generally, for any measurable function $f$, $f(X,Y,T)$ is independent of $Z$.

Comment: @forgottenarrow, Thank you for your comments! I did want to apply the result somewhere you mentioned. But after I looked up some books, I found they all assert that the measurable function $f$ is real-valued (i.e. mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^1$ ). In my question, this function is mapping from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, so that's my confusion.

Comment: @tobinz - the $\mathbb{R}^1$ version already implies _each component_ of the vector is independent of $Z$...  :)

Comment: @antkam, Exactly! But in general each component being independent of Z does not imply they are jointly independent of Z?

Comment: oh, you are right...!  sorry.  I will leave my erroneous comment up, as a warning for others.  :)

Comment: Here's a proof outline of the result using measure theory. The character limit made this tough to write, so let me know if anything is unclear.

Let $(X,Y,Z)$ be a random vector. Let $f$ be any measurable function. Then for any measurable set $B$, there exists an $A \in \sigma(X,Y)$ such that $\{f(X,Y) \in B\} = \{(X,Y)\in A\}$. However, the product sigma algebra is generated from rectangles so we can assume WLOG that $\{(X,Y) \in A\} = \{X\in A_X\}\cap\{Y\in A_Y\}$.

$$P(f(X,Y)\in B,Z \in C) = P(X\in A_X,Y\in A_Y,Z \in C) = P(f(X,Y)\in B)P(Z \in C)$$

Note: $f$ can take values in $R^2$.